# Output as a matrix in fortran

Tags: matrix, binary, fortran

I want the output as a matrix in a binary format but I keep getting it as a single long array. Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong

```
             program ascii_to_binary
              implicit none

c  
c declarations
                 integer iw,jy,i
                 real  A(47,52),z(47,52),undef
                 real  x(47,52)
                 logical exist 


c----------------------------------------------------
c read in the index, insert name of file in input_file

               undef =  -9999.         

c read in the index, insert name of file in input_file

         inquire(file="weekly_mean_sce.txt", exist=exist)
         if (exist) then
         print *,"Exist"

         open(43,file='weekly_mean_sce.txt',status='old')

         do jy=1,47

         read(43,*) A(jy,:)


          enddo  
          print *, maxval(A)
         write(6,*)'read in input data' 

         else 
         print *,"not there"
         end if
         x=reshape(A,(/47,52/))


          OPEN(UNIT=15, FILE="sce.dat",ACTION="write")
          do i=1,47
          write(15, '(F9.2)')( real(x(i,iw)) ,iw=1,52)
          end do 
          write(15,"(F9.2)") x(1:47,1:52) 


          END PROGRAM ascii_to_binary
```

Comment: Which binary format you want? What is "single long array"? Try `access=stream` and get rid of the formats. Read your fortran manual about unformatted IO.

Comment: file extensions have no significance in fortran (guessing why you expected binary from that)

Answer (score 0):

Normal Fortran I/O uses a record structure.  If you want unformatted I/O while keeping the record structure, I would recommend

```
  open(15,file="sce.dat", form="unformatted")
  do iw=1,52    ! Better to use named constants here
     write (15) x(:,iw)
  end do
```

This writes out the values in the natural Fortran array order, where the storage order is a(1,1), a(2,1) etc, plus some additional information (record markers) to identify where a record starts and where it ends.

If you do not need the record structure, you can just use

```
  open(15,file="sce.dat",form="unformatted",access="stream")
  write (15) x
```